# Disable scrolling to next slide in Powerpoint Edit Mode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-powerpoint, scrolling

When editing in PowerPoint lately (using 2010, but occurs in other versions I believe), I have often pasted in large images that are larger than the screen. I'll then scroll down (with my trackpad) to try to get to the bottom of the image to resize/crop the image to the appropriate slide. However, I end up scrolling a little bit too far which causes PowerPoint to progress to the next slide. When I go back to the previous slide, the screen is not all the way at the bottom (usually 1 or 2 scroll-lengths away), leading me to try again, and usually progress to the next slide again. Comedy ensues.

Is there any hope (other than training my muscle memory to go manually click on scroll down arrow, scrolling down one click at at time, the technique I fall back on after overshooting 3 or 4 times)? Any of these could solve the issue:

1. Configuring PowerPoint to not scroll to the next slide when using the mouse wheel scroll action (thus limiting the scrolling to only the current slide)
2. Learning a keyboard shortcut for PowerPoint to scroll to the bottom of the content on the slide (which may be below the bottom of the viewable slide)
3. Have PowerPoint automatically resize images to fit on the page upon pasting, or knowing a keyboard shortcut to auto resize the selected image to the bounds of the slide.
4. Some other action that you've thought of that I have not.

Comment: Are you trying to create a slide background? **Note:** Powerpoint seems to be resizing the images for me on insert. Is it not doing that for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> > Some other action that you've thought of that I have not.

Possibly a free add-in that turns the fix into a one-click and does some other useful stuff.

Disclaimer:  I wrote it. It's called THOR and is available here:
https://pptools.com/free/FAQ00002-THOR-The-Hammer.htm

(Note: I edited this reply in May/2023 to remove a reference to an earlier add-in that I no longer recommend)

Comment: this plugin doesn't seem to do what op asks

Answer (score 5):

1. select all slides
2. go to slide master
3. create a massive textbox with at least a word at the very top...move this box to the top of the slide
4. create a second massive textbox with at least a word at the very bottom...move this box to the bottom of the slide
5. save, exit slide master, and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

I've tried inserting large photos in PowerPoint 2007 and it kept on resizing them to fit the slide even with some padding, so I guess you're using PP 2003 or earlier.

However, no matter what version you're using, the solution is the same. You can either **zoom out of the slide** (in 2003 & earlier, it's a drop-down in the Standard toolbar; in 2007 & later, it's a slider in the lower right-hand corner of the screen) or **right-click the image and select the option called size** (if you don't have it, go to properties).