# Is there a built-in way to disable scrolling within the edit mode of PowerPoint 2013?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, scrolling

There's a very similar question here: [Disable scrolling to next slide in Powerpoint Edit Mode](https://superuser.com/questions/378497/disable-scrolling-to-next-slide-in-powerpoint-edit-mode), but unfortunately the two answers don't really answer what the title of the question appears to ask.

In PowerPoint 2013 when you're in the edit mode the scroll wheel switches between slides. Unfortunately for me my mouse's scroll wheel is very temperamental and a slight touch of it is enough to trigger it. This isn't an issue when viewing web pages or editing text documents as the scroll usually isn't enough to do anything, but in PowerPoint it appears that even the slightest of scroll will change from one slide to the next.

I want to either disable the scroll wheel completely in PowerPoint or set it to instead scroll on the current slide view rather than move onto the next slide. Is this at all possible?

Comment: I think you would better of buying a new mouse if your current one is so temperamental.

Comment: @DavidPostill definitely. Unfortunately that requires money. I've been using this mouse in its current state for over a year now and I've not really had any big problems with it until now. It's really annoying to be half way through editing a slide to have it move onto the next one without you wanting it to though, so I figured this would be something they'd let you disable.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting how much the scroll wheel moves in Control Panel? Maybe that will reduce its sensitivity?

Comment: Another thing you might try is using AutoHotKey - have a read of this, it might help you: http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/41161-how-to-disable-scrolling-when-powerpoint-is-active/

Comment: It might help to adjust the number of lines to scroll setting in Mouse Settings (Win10) or on the Wheel tab in Mouse Properties dialog box (Control Panel | Mouse). Or both.

Answer (score 0):

This [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org/) script does exactly what you want – tested:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class PPTFrameClass ahk_exe POWERPNT.EXE
WheelUp::return
WheelDown::return
#IfWinActive
```

Features:

- mouse wheel is disabled *only when* main window is active

  - if you occasionally need to use the wheel, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then it works
- mouse wheel works without restrictions (as normally) if presentation window is active

Happy presenting!

---

From a [comment below](https://superuser.com/questions/992889/is-there-a-built-in-way-to-disable-scrolling-within-the-edit-mode-of-powerpoint/1137048?noredirect=1#comment2108210_1137048):

Also make sure to set the `#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200` in the AHK script.

Comment: But he does want to disable it in edit mode not in present mode.

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck – thanks for heads-up. Answer corrected.

Comment: now its kind of working, it just disabled all scrolling. Which is a partial solution to what he wrote here *I want to either disable the scroll wheel completely in PowerPoint or set it to instead scroll on the current slide view rather than move onto the next slide. Is this at all possible?*

Comment: @PhilRoggenbuck - not easily using the AHK. After high effort, perhaps the main window can be reverse engineered and then scroll wheel will send the message only to that panel. Perhaps someone with advanced experience can achieve it in AHK.

Comment: Yeah I know :) But good idea to do that with AHK

Comment: Also make sure to set the `#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200` in the AHK script. When using this solution.